# How to use celery in flask app to send task from one server to the other

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have two flask apps, one on server A, the other on server B. What I want to do is generate an asynchronous task from the app on server A on some condition and send it to the app on server B(i.e. invoke a function on server B). I think celery send task method would be used for it but don't know how to use it.

let's say I have a function 'func' in my app on server B

```
def func(x):
    return x
```

I want to invoke 'func' in another function 'somefunc' in my app on server A, something like this:

```
def somefunc(x):
    if condition is True:
        func(x)
```

How would I use celery to implement this logic? Please help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

On service A you would have this:

```
from celery.execute import send_task


@app.route('/')
def endpoint():
    if cond(x):
        send_task(
           'task_service_b',
           (param1, param2),
           exchange='if u have a specific one',
           routing_key='a routing key'
        )
```

On service b,you would need to have the app listening on 'a routing key' and bound to the exchange 'if u have a specific one',

```
messaging_exchange = Exchange('if u have a specific one')
bindings = (
    binding(messaging_exchange, routing_key=routing_key)
    for routing_key in ['a routing key']
)

default_binding = binding(
    Exchange(celery_app.conf.task_default_queue),
    routing_key=celery_app.conf.task_default_queue
)

celery_app.conf.task_queues = [
    # default queue has same routing key as name of the queue
    Queue(celery_app.conf.task_default_queue, [default_binding]),
    Queue('service.b.queue', list(bindings))
]
```

otherwise you can bypass all and just `send_task` to the service b queue.
you will need a celery worker on service b as the task will need to be consumed by the worker

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from your phrasing that you're running different apps on servers A and B. If they were the same app, using the same celery broker and backend, then named queues with one queue being served by a celery worker that's only running on B could give you the effect you want.

If A and B are running different code, a safe approach is to have the asynchronous task on A make an HTTP request to and endpoint on B, with that endpoint calling the function and sending the answer back in an HTTP response for the async task in A to deal with.

Elaborating:

A slow-running async task (say, in tasks.py)

```
@celery.task
def slow_running_task():
    ...
```

that's configured to run in a specific queue

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'tasks.slow_running_task': {'queue': 'slow'},
    ...
```

can be run on a specific server by only running a celery worker with `-Q slow` on that server.

There are nuances. It's worth skimming the celery docs.

Comment: yes, I'm using same celery broker and backend. It would be great if you could elaborate this method a little for me? I can't make an HTTP request because I would have to wait till the response is received, whereas, I want to run the task in the background separate from the app